# Can anyone please explain how the grouping is taking place in this example?

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, data.table

```
out_df <-df[, .(SumAmount =
                        sum(ifelse(
                        is.na(Amount), 0, ifelse(is.nan(Amount), 0, Amount)
                        ))),
                        by = .(
                              Class,
                              AccountType,
                              AccountSubType,
                              AccountDrillDown = NaturalAccount,
                              Country
                            )]
```

I am able to understand the entire process except for the part where AccountDrillDown = NaturalAccount is happening, can anyone please explain how the grouping will take place in this case?

Comment: It's renaming the column to AccountDrillDown

Comment: @FrankZhang Thank you! Also, when I am trying to do the same in python using df.groupby(by=items).apply(lambda group: group['Amount'].sum()) I am not getting the same output. 
(items is the list of the columns used in "by" of R code). Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Its better that you add this as a new question and labelled with `python` `pandas`

Comment: Please do not leave questions unanswered, either provide self answer or delete the question.